# How to put conditions on indices of product

Tags: interpolation, products

I'm trying to solve for the Lagrangian form of the interpolation polynomial. Right now, I'm just trying to solve for the $l_i(x)$ values which are equal to $l_i(x)=\prod_{j\neq i, j=1}^{n}{\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}} $. Where $n$ is the length of the list of x values. My code right now is:

```
LagrangeL[i_, xList_] := 
 Product[(x - xList[j])/(xList[i] - xList[j]) Boole[i != j], {j, 1, 
   Length[xList]}]
```

This is giving me `Indeterminate` for `LagrangeL[1, {1, 2}]` and I'm not sure why. Is there a way to make the condition of $j \neq i$ in the product index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: your xList is a List, so index into it with [[ ]] rather than [ ], and you need to keep the denominator from evaluating.

```
LagrangeL[i_, xList_] := Product[If[i != j, 
   (x - xList[[j]])/(xList[[i]] - xList[[j]]), 1], {j, 1, Length[xList]}] 

2 - x
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. One more question now, am I able to set a new function equal to the output of this? So like f[x_]:=LagrangeL[1,{1,2}]; f[0].

Comment: Sure -- the output is a polynomial, so you can work with it as with any polynomial. But what you probablby want is: `f[x_] = LagrangeL[1, {1, 2}]` so that you can have f[0]=2, f[2]=0, etc.